# Extract Image Link with Nokogiri and Xpath

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am trying to use xpath and nokogiri to extract the image URL of google images. when I right-click an image and copy its xpath, I get the following:

//*[@id="irc_cc"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img

However, when I put this into the nokogiri xpath call, nothing returns. Any ideas on how I might capture the URL to the image? Thank you!

```
require "open-uri"
require "mechanize"
require "net/http"

base_url = "https://www.google.com/search?
tbm=isch&tbs=isz:lt,islt:vga&q=Analog%20Bar%20San%20Diego%20Burgers"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(base_url))
doc.xpath('//*[@id="irc_cc"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img').each do |node|
  puts node
end
```

Comment: I can't find any html element with id `irc_cc`

Comment: Hmm ok so I did view source and I dont see anything with irc_cc either. The way I got this Xpath was by right-clicking the image in Google and clicking Inspect Element, then right-clicking the element and clicking Copy XPath. Is there a better way to be doing this?

Comment: I do understand that "copy XPATH" is handy and fast, but it looks like this functionality has a bug... You always can build your XPATH manually